# Text formatting issue in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, html, uitableview, uiwebview

I've a `webview` which is placed inside a custom table view cell, since dynamic data is to be loaded in to this `webview`, some text gets cut off as per current `webview` frame.

So I'm asking is there any method to dynamically set size of webview so as to see just first two lines of `webview` content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the very nice article with code example, Just check how do they taking care of the same issue, which you are facing.

[Fast UITableViewCell with a UIWebView](http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/fast-uitableviewcell-with-a-uiwebview/)

Implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` menthod of `UITableViewDelegate`, and get the text of two line.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Try with below to get the height for one line.

```
float lineHeight = [myText sizeWithFont:myTextFont ].height; // Calculate the height of one line.
```

Multiply it with 2 and assign it as your row height.. :)

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, but how to get the text of two line?